# How do I calculate the tangent to a point on a circle?

Tags: java, geometry, slick

I have a line that is from the center of a circle to a point on it's edge that is changing constantly (radius is drawn to a point orbiting a circle)
I want to make a line tangential to the circle whose midpoint is always the orbiting point. I know how to do it on paper but coding it in logic is the problem. Can someone show me how or point me to resources that I could use that would help me?

```
    public Line calculateTangent(Circle ball){

    //the point orbiting the circle
    circleEdge = new Vector2f((float)(radius*Math.cos(angle*Math.PI/180f)), (float)(radius*Math.sin(angle*Math.PI/180f)));
    //the line that I want to be perpendicular to at all times
    radiusLine = new Line(ball.getCenterX(), ball.getCenterY(), circleEdge.getX(), circleEdge.getY());
    //no idea how to do this last part
    perpendicular = 

    }
```

Comment: Little bit unclear, can you post some visuals? Manual hand written work on paper?

Answer (score 2):

In 2D there's a simple trick for getting a perpendicular vector:

```
Vector2 Rotate90(Vector2 original)
{
    return new Vector2(original.y, -original.x);
}
```

(ie. swap the vector's x & y components and negate one of them)

Whether this rotates the vector clockwise or counterclockwise depends on your coordinate system. If it's pointing the wrong way for your use case, just put the negative sign on `original.y` instead of `original.x`

Answer (score 1):

The cross product of two vectors is a third vector that is perpendicular to both inputs.

```
public Line calculateTangent(Circle ball)
{
  //Unit circle at (0,0,0)
  //Vector3, radius = 1.0f
  circleEdge = new Vector3((float)(Math.cos(angle*Math.PI/180f)), 0, (float)(Math.sin(angle*Math.PI/180f)));

  //Visual only
  radiusLine = new Line(ball.getCenterX(), ball.getCenterY(), circleEdge.getX(), circleEdge.getY());

  //Circle lies in XZ plane so (0,1,0) is perpendicular to any point on the circumference
  //perpendicular must be perpendicular to both circleEdge and (0,1,0)
  //Result of cross-product is a direction away from (0,0,0)
  perpendicular = circleEdge.Cross(Vector3(0, 1, 0));

  //Unit circle has convenient radius of 1.0f
  //Scale to correct radius
  circleEdge *= radius;

  //Everything is at (0,0,0)
  //Translate to real position
  circleEdge += ball.Center();

  //perpendicular is a direction away from (0,0,0)
  //Convert to direction away from circleEdge
  perpendicular += circleEdge;
}
```